# C++ Template Function No Matching Call

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, compiler-errors

I'm trying to provide a generic mapping function over STL containers such as `vector` and `list`. Here's my implementation:

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>


template<class A, class B, template <class> class F>
F<B> fmap(F<A> &functor, std::function<B(A)> &f)
{
  F<B> newFunctor;

  return std::transform(begin(functor)
                , end(functor)
            , begin(newFunctor)     
            , f);
}
```

But when I try and call it with the code:

```
vector<int> v;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  v.push_back(i);
}

vector<int> w = fmap(v, [](int i) { return i + 1; });
```

I get a `no matching function call` error.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Since when is a vector a _functor_? `fmap`'s arguments are named weirdly.

Comment: The next problem you're going to have is that you need `std::back_inserter(newFunctor)` instead of `begin(newFunctor)` since `newFunctor` is empty.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things wrong in the code. The first thing, as already pointed out, is that the `std::vector` template takes 2 template arguments, the stored type and the allocator. Even though the second is defaulted to be the instantiation of `std::allocator` with the stored type, it is still an argument to the template.

The second problem you will encounter is that although you can create a `std::function` from a lambda, the lambda expression is not a `std::function`, so the compiler will fail to match the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

**[vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)** had 2 template arguments

```
template < class T, class Alloc = allocator<T> > class vector;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain some independence from the exact declaration structure of the container type by assuming that all applicable container types are template classes whose first parameter is the value type. For output, produce a container with a different value type and all other template parameters the same. This is possible with a type trait that can rebind containers with differing value type:

```
template <typename Container>
struct container_rebind;

template <template <typename...> class Container, typename ValueType, typename... OtherArgs>
struct container_rebind<Container<ValueType, OtherArgs...>> {
    template <typename NewValueType>
    using rebind = Container<NewValueType, OtherArgs...>;
};

template <typename Container, typename NewValueType>
using ContainerRebind = typename container_rebind<Container>::template rebind<NewValueType>;
```

so, e.g., `ContainerRebind<std::vector<int>, double>` is `std::vector<double>`. It's possible to partially specialize `container_rebind` to support other kinds of container templates, such as those that have non-type template parameters. Adding support for `std::array`, for example, is left to the reader.